# Gimbal Lock: why is it a problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, gyroscopes

I was watching the video [Gimble Lock - Explained](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrUCBOlJdt4), by videodumper, about the gimbal lock problem. I understood that during rotations it could happen that one DOF disappear. Looking at the middle part of the video (min 3.22) can be seen that two planes are stuck in only one plane. For this reason performing rotations along  X axis is the same of performing rotations along Z axis.

Why are these two planes stuck together? For my imagination it does not seem so complicated to separate them and to continue having 3 DOFs. But I think that something eludes me...

Comment: Gimbal lock is not "a problem", at least not one that one can't solve with money. Four-gimbal mechanisms that prevent gimbal lock have been available for quite some time for applications that need them, like fighter aircraft that have to be able to take on every possible attitude. A Boeing 747 does not... once it's flying upside down, there are bigger problems than losing inertial guidance. That gimbals can lock up is a geometric problem: there are positions in which two axes are parallel, i.e. rotations around either result in exactly the same movement, i.e. as you observe a loss of one DOF.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I lose one DOF is it a problem? I mean, it will happen for just a tiny period of time (only when the two planes are overlapping), and then just a small variation of one of the two overlapping planes make my situation to become "normal" with 3 DOF, correct?

Comment: The number of degrees of freedom of the motion of the aircraft or spacecraft does not change, but the technical system that is supposed to measure them can suddenly have one less than is needed to describe that motion. I am almost certain that a detailed error analysis of a multi-gimbal system will reveal that gimbal-lock is just the worst case of an increasingly deteriorating measurement accuracy of the system as it comes ever closer to that state. My suspicion is that one should always try to keep the axes as orthogonal to each other as possible to retain max. accuracy.

Comment: Gimbal lock will no doubt be a problem in real world control applications.  A computer control algorithm that is flying an aircraft (e.g., autopilot) needs those 3 DOF to function properly.  If 1 DOF "disappears", it is very likely that the computer will execute improper corrective action on the aircraft's control surfaces.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838/why-is-gimbal-lock-an-issue/1858

Answer (score 2):

The planes are not deliberately stuck together - they just happen to coincide when one rotation (by 90 degrees) has dragged one plane of rotation to coincide with another. After that, you can no longer distinguish between rotation about the two axes whose planes coincide - so you have gone from three degrees of freedom to just two.

When this happens, you can no longer describe an arbitrary motion for the next moment in time - there are certain directions of motion that cannot be described (if you think of rotation as a vector pointing "somewhere" in space, you cannot reach every direction in space with just two basis vectors).

Even when you "unlock", and there are once again three distinct directions, two of the basis vectors point in almost the same direction - which means that certain rotations can only be described by the superposition of very large (and nearly opposite) rotations about the two axes that are nearly parallel.

This just makes the problem of describing motion with these axes ill-conditioned. And that is what is called gimbal lock.